# How to set required validation for b-form-checkbox-group in bootstrap-vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

My code is

```
 <b-form-checkbox-group multiple v-model="fieldselect" :options="selections" class="mb-3" ></b-form-checkbox-group>
```

How to set this as a required field in vue js>

Comment: use `required` property such as they mention in their [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

just change
"<b-form-checkbox-group ..."
to
"<b-form-checkbox ...
if it is one selector

Comment: How would this make the checkbox[es] required?